# How do I enter the time of day and time deltas as variables into a regression model in python?

Tags: regression, time-series, variable

I want to predict adherence from the variability in times of day at which medications are taken. However, I can't enter variables which describe this variability in the times of day into the linear regression model because they are all datetime or timedelta variables. How should I represent these variables to make them compatible with regression in sklearn?
Thanks!

Comment: Think I might just represent them all as float64 of number of minutes into the day- I.e 10:16:48 is 616.8 minutes into the day?

Comment: Could you please add some Python code that demonstrates what you have tried so far? Please use [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to add your code.

Answer (score 1):

maybe just use several dummy variables from 0:23 or if it does not need to be that precise something between 0:3 as morning, midday, evening and midnight?
That should work to explain possible differences.

Comment: Thanks - I need keep the temporal granularity at the hours and minute level. What do you think is the best way to dummy code that?

Comment: Uf okay, that is a huge amount of dummys, tbh I'm not sure if in that case it is the best solution...
You can check this link to see how it would be done, but I think that would be too much hard coding.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52792139/python-create-timerseries-dummy-variable-based-on-datetime-list

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment your answer, so I'll do it this way. I would be realy carefull with this method, given the way linear regression works.

y = ßx + e

Now if x is the time of the day, ß tells you how a change (of i.e 1 minute), holding all other things equal effects y (what ever that might be, I'm not sure I got your problem correctly). This assumes as the name implies a linear connection, so y can just shrink/raise with or against time, meaning, if you create your float as growing with the hour, taking the pill at 23:59 would have the biggest effect while taking it a minute later would shrink that down to nothing, which seems unrealistic to me.

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/532908/edit) your original answer instead of posting another one?

Comment: Of course, but given that it is an answer to her new idea, I'll wait till she edited it to be a comment.